# Can we integrate a framework written in different language than objective c and swift in ios apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

Lets say, I have a framework written in python and i want to integrate the same in my ios apps? can it done if not, please suggest any other alternative?

Comment: Never seen a Python framework for iOS, but there are other libraries written in other languages like C++, which works in iOS Apps.